# Is it necessary to have my full name (including middle name) on my student pilot license?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, checkride, fsdo

So my student pilot license is missing a middle name, but my drivers license, written exam, and passport all have it printed.

I've spoken with the DPE, and he says it may be an issue, or it may not, and that he is going to look into it.

I've called FSDO, airmen certification branch, and other DMVesque organizations, and they all seem to say the same thing:

> Oh, you need to talk to (insert amorphous bureaucracy here)

Does anyone know who I actually need to talk to, or if this is even an issue? Do I just need to call FSDO and insist that they fix the issue, or what?

The DPE said that with the written exam being OK it may be a non-issue. Would love to hear from a DPE on here if possible.

Comment: The FAA people must not be paying much attention lately. This is the 3rd licence discrepancy question on SE in two months

Comment: Contact the person who issued it to you Ie. The AME/DPE/CFI etc.

Comment: @RyanMortensen the AME no longer practices...

Comment: @OneChillDude I had the same issue. My passport doesn't have a middle name field, and includes my middle-name as part of my first-name. My DPE noticed this and hence left the middle-name field blank on IACRA, and followed what my passport had. So, I believe the Passport/Birth Certificate holds more value when identifying yourself.

Comment: @OneChillDude ouch.  I suppose the real question is whether anything official says that your SPL/medical *must* have a middle name on it.  Maybe contact the Civil Aerospace Medical Institute in Oklahoma City.  They are the authority on medicals.

Comment: I have a meeting with FSDO on Wednesday. I'll report back soon

Answer (score 11):

Alright so here is the outcome:

I called FSDO, spoke with a real nice guy who told me to give him a call if I couldn't handle this online.

Called a zillion bureaucracies, all telling me to call someone else.

Called the nice guy at FSDO, set up an appointment for a name **correction** not a name change. Went to the appointment and was in and out in under an hour.

If you're having the same issue, I would recommend bringing every official identification you've got: passport, birth certificate, drivers license, etc.

**Tl;DR** call FSDO and tell them you need a name **correction**. NOT a name change. Can't stress that enough.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the outcome!  Did you happen to learn whether or not your AME *could* have helped you if he/she were still practicing?

Comment: @RyanMortensen I did not find that out, however I am 99% sure that the AME can reissue a medical, however that will cost money, FSDO is free

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue myself (less than a week before PPL checkride of course). In the time since this question there has been a clarification to this exact scenario (middle initial on the student license). https://dperesources.com/clarification-on-name-mismatches-from-afs720-middle-name-middle-initial-discrepancy/

If I'm reading it correctly this indicates that you don't need to get a new license, but you still need to make sure that your middle name on the checkride application is your full middle name and not your middle initial (hopefully I can get the FSDO to go and change it tomorrow when they open).